# accessing jquery variable in PHP in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to access javascript variable in php of the same page.

I'm doing a AJAX call and I get a JSON data.

This AJAX call is being fired upon a dropdown change.

I wanted to run few PHP functions on the same in the AJAX function based on the dropdown value.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: { dropdown1: dropdown1, 
                    variable2: variable2
                },
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(result) {

                // chart  functions

                <?php

                    $dropdown_val = $_POST['dropdown1']

                ?>

            })
```

Is it possible that I can send the form value inside of the page itself to PHP function?

Suggest me please...

Comment: No, it's not possible, at least not like that.

Comment: Any other way to do it? I wanted access a javascript variable in PHP of the same page.

Comment: It's 10 years people comes with the same question, which has been asked hundreds of times on SO. This should be taught in elementary school imo. In order to be constructive, read about HTTP protocol and JSON serialisation, that's everything you need to know ^^

Comment: It may be 10 years that people are coming with the same question. But this is my 1st yest :). And now I see that for about 10 years you  people are giving the same answer that it must be taught in the elementary level rather than finding out a way alternative for it ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. You'd have to run another AJAX call and put your PHP inside that. Alternatively, couldn't you put the PHP inside the `data.php` file and run it from within that?